# How to handle the if statement in a view called from multiple places when passing a variable to compact

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have the following function in the controller:

```
public function tasks(Client $client)
{
$tasks = $client->tasks;
$client_name = $client->name;
return view('task.index', compact('tasks','client_name'));
}
```

and as task_index is called from multiple places, I am handling h1 as shown below:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
@if($client_name)
<h1>List of overall customer tasks {{$client_name}}</h1>
@else
<h1>List of tasks</h1>
@endif
</div>
```

only when I click on the button to show all the tasks I get the error

**Undefined variable $client_name**

so the if is not working.

Can anyone tell me how to do please?

Comment: `task.index` refers to the **index** file in the **task** folder. But you are calling `task_index` file. Why?

Comment: it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Blade `@isset` directive rather than `@if`:

```
@isset($client_name)
    <h1>List of overall customer tasks {{$client_name}}</h1>
@else
    <h1>List of tasks</h1>
@endisset
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using $client_name in different blade, Try to share your variable using View::share() in the AppServiceProvider it will act as component and you can use it across all the blade template

from AppServiceProvider class

```
$tasks = $client->tasks;
$client_name = $client->name;
```

ex: View::share(['client_name'=>$client_name] i already use it in my project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple blade files within each other, you must pass the variable you want to re-use in each subsequent blade file

eg.

```
<h1>List of overall customer tasks {{$client_name}}</h1>

@include('another.blade.php', ['client_name' => $client_name])
```